# Find out the current frequency of the CPU

Tags: delphi, winapi, visual-c++

The Windows 8 Task manager shows the current (not maximum) frequency of the CPU (e.g. 1.2 GHz). Is there a way to get this frequency with the Windows API? Preferrably using Delphi or Visual C++.

Answer (score 5):

I would look into WMI, specifically, the `CurrentClockSpeed` property of the `Win32_Processor` class.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: CurrentClockSpeed does not take any overclocking into account, so it has different values than CPU-Z. (tested with wbemtest.exe that is located in system32\wbem

Comment: It works on my overclocked system, so I'm not sure what issue you are running into.

Comment: On my overclocked system CPU-Z displays an idle frequency of 1240 MHz (which is correct). The CurrentClockSpeed WMI value is 1173 (which would be the default idle clock frequency, without any overclocking).