# How to get CPU speed from Delphi 64 bit application (XE5)?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe5

We are in the process of migrating our application suite to 64 bit using Delphi XE5. In our about boxes we display the CPU speed. The routine we currently use is 32 bit assembly and therefore will not compile under 64 bit.

Is there a native way to retrieve CPU speed from within Delphi 64 bit?

Comment: I feel a WMI answer coming, where are you @RRUZ? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate, [`Find out the current frequency of the CPU`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14916327/576719). The WMI interface is the same for x32 and x64.

Comment: Do you want the speed per core? And what do you need: the actual CPU speed or the advertised speed?

Comment: check my answer, which i think is what you need exactly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your platform is windows and you want the advertised CPU speed then you can simply check the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0\~MHz` DWORD value in the Registry:

```
program SO21757165;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Registry,
  Windows,
  System.SysUtils;

function GetCPUSpeed : String;

var
  Reg : TRegistry;

begin
 Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
 try
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0') then
   begin
    Result := Format('CPU Speed is %dMHz', [Reg.ReadInteger('~MHz')]);
    Reg.CloseKey;
   end;
 finally
  Reg.Free;
 end;
end;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    Writeln(GetCPUSpeed);
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**EDIT**

rewrote above code snippet to a compileable example. This example has been verified in XE7and works in 32bit and 64 bit environments (with UAC enabled)

Comment: This requires Administrator permissions.

Comment: @DoctorLai: no you don't, everyone has READ permission on those keys. Check regedit if you don't believe me...

Comment: for 32 bit yes, you are right, but compile the same code under XE8 64-bit, you will need administrator to get the correct value, otherwise, it will return empty string. just tried that.

Comment: check my answer. I came across this problem yesterday and thus re-write the 32-bit assembly to 64-bit code. It works perfect.

Comment: @DoctorLai, registry read works for me on W7 64 bit compiled for 64 bit platform. Just call `Reg.OpenKey('HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0',FALSE)` and it works.

Comment: It depends on your UAC settings or/and the application's permissions. Anyway, the registry value is a fixed value so you will get the same value using your code.

Comment: For read-only access, you should be using `Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly()` instead of `Reg.OpenKey()`. Otherwise, at lease consider using `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` instead of `KEY_READ`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: agreed, adapted my answer

Answer (score 1):

The registry isn't a good solution because it might be altered and may be subject to user permission (read registry).

The following code can be compiled under Delphi XE-8 both 32-bit and 64-bit, following the SAME principle, so this should give you consistent values in both 32-bit and 64-bit.

```
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
function GetCpuClockCycleCount: Int64; assembler; register;
asm
    dw 310Fh // rdtsc
    shl rdx, 32
    or rax, rdx
end;
{$ENDIF}

function GetCPUSpeed: double;
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
const
  DelayTime = 500; // measure time in ms
var
  TimerHi, TimerLo: DWOrd;
  PriorityClass, Priority: Integer;
begin
  PriorityClass := GetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess);
  Priority := GetthreadPriority(GetCurrentthread);
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
  SetthreadPriority(GetCurrentthread, thread_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
  Sleep(10);
  asm
    dw 310Fh // rdtsc
    mov TimerLo, eax
    mov TimerHi, edx
  end;
  Sleep(DelayTime);
  asm
    dw 310Fh // rdtsc
    sub eax, TimerLo
    sbb edx, TimerHi
    mov TimerLo, eax
    mov TimerHi, edx
  end;
  SetthreadPriority(GetCurrentthread, Priority);
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess, PriorityClass);
  Result := TimerLo / (1000.0 * DelayTime);
end;
{$ELSE}
const
  DelayTime = 500;
var
  x, y: UInt64;
  PriorityClass, Priority: Integer;
begin
  PriorityClass := GetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess);
  Priority      := GetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread);
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
  SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
  Sleep(10);
  x := GetCpuClockCycleCount;
  Sleep(DelayTime);
  y := GetCpuClockCycleCount;
  SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, Priority);
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess, PriorityClass);
  Result := ((y - x) and $FFFFFFFF) / (1000 * DelayTime);
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access this information using WMI.

GLibWMI components can be found on this website (http://neftali.clubdelphi.com) or sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/glibwmi/).
The current version is 1.8b and has a component called **TProcessorInfo** with which you can get this information.

It has properties like (**CurrentclockSpeed** or **MaxClockSpeed**).

One of the samples that comes with the library is about this class (TProcessorInfo).

[image]

The source code is available so you can expand it to access other WMI classes if necessary.

If you don't want to use Components, you can get code neccesary to get this properties using te tool ["WMI Delphi code Creator"](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) created by [Rodrigo Ruz](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/about/).

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically each core in your CPU can operate at a different frequency you can use this WMI example to get the frequency of each "Core" although it counts Logical cores and not physical.

Here is a VCL example

```
uses : ComObj,ActiveX;

procedure  GetProcessorPerformanceInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  Form5.ListBox1.Clear;
  Form5.Tfreq.Clear;
  Form5.Tusage.Clear;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\WMI', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM ProcessorPerformance','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Form5.ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('frequency   %d',[Integer(FWbemObject.frequency)])+Format('%s',[String(FWbemObject.InstanceName)]));// Uint32
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

There is a very good tool you can use to create these, this was made using Delphi WMI Code generator from https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/